# Elementary Algebra Inequality question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
\frac{1}{x-1} < -\frac{1}{x+2}
$$

(see [this page in wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F%28x-1%29%29+%3C+%28-1%2F%28x%2B2%29%29))

Ok, so I think the main problem is that I don't really know how to do these questions. What I tried to do was move $-1/(x + 2)$ to the LHS and then tried to get a common denominator. I ended up with

$$
\frac{(x + 2) + (x -1)}{(x-1)(x+2)} < 0.
$$
So then I went 
$$
\frac{2x + 1}{(x-1)(x+2)}<0
$$
and got $x < -1/2$  and $x \ne 1$ and $x\ne -2$. Therefore, the answer should be $x$ is $(-\infty, -2)$ or $(-2, -1/2)$. But it's not.

Comment: A product of three numbers is negative when all three of them are negative, or only one is negative.

Comment: huh? What are you referring to?

Comment: You have the product of $2x+1$ with $(x-1)^{-1}$ and $(x+2)^{-1}$, don't you?

Comment: yeah. so then 2x + 1 becomes x < -1/2

Comment: We will want to get rid of the denominator, by multiplying by $(x+2)9x-1)$. If $x\lt -2$, we will be multiplying by a positive, also when $x\gt 1$. When $-2\lt x\lt 1$ we will be multiplying by a negative, and the inequality is reversed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So then what do I do??

Comment: I imagine the answers have made it all clear. Sorry about the $$(x+2)9x-1)$ instead of $(x+2)(x-1)$: sticky shift key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the form $\frac{a}{b} < 0$ you know there are only two options:
$a < 0$, $b>0$ and $a>0$, $b<0$, because $a$ and $b$ need to differ in sign for the fraction to be negative.

First case:

$$
2x+1 < 0 \implies x < -\frac12
\\
(x-1)(x+2) > 0 \implies x < ...
$$

and then repeat for the other case

Comment: Thanks for keeping it simple.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{x-1}<-\frac{1}{x+2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+2}<0 \rightarrow$

$\frac{(x+2)+(x-1)}{(x+2)(x-1)} <0 \rightarrow \frac{(x+2)+(x-1)}{(x+2)(x-1)}((x+2)(x-1)^2<0  \rightarrow (x+2+x-1)(x+2)(x+1)<0 $

for $x$ different to $-2,1$. (-2 and 1 arent soultions cause they are undefined.)

using the fact that rational functions are continuous wherever they are defined and the intermediate value theorem:

$(x+2+x-1)(x+2)(x-1)=2(x+\frac{1}{2})(x+2)(x+1)<0$

Since the polynomial 2(x+\frac{3}{2})(x+2)(x+1) has three roots:(each with multiplicity 1)

$-\frac{1}{2},-1,-2$ and -1000 is a solution to the inequality we can know that the solution set is $(-\infty,-2)\cup (-1,-\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: how did you get $((x+2)(x+1))^2$?

Comment: i multiply both sides by that (its standard in this type of problems) its usefull because since squares of real numbers are non negative im preserving the sign, and therefore its also gonna be positive unless its 0. But it can only be 0 if x is a root of the polynomial.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an error on the first line, it should be $1/(x-1)$ instead of $1/(x+1)$.

Comment: oops. fixing fail sorry guys

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x+2}$.  As $f$ isn't defined at $x=1$ and $x=-2$ and $f(x)=0\iff x=1/2$ the sign of $f$ on the intervals $(-\infty,-2)$, $(-2,1/2)$, $(1/2,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ can't change, because $f$ is continuous.